# What metric should I use for custom calculated fields or comparison charts in Google data studio?

Tags: google-data-studio

I've been through almost all the blogs that highlight the difference between users, sessions, record count, new users, returning users, page views, etc. But I'm not able to understand which one should be used in what scenario? Ex. If I want to find out which page, or which part of the page people view more, how should I do that?

Which metric will make more sense in what scenarios?